# Certain Images missing and videos aborted in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: html, image, internet-explorer, video, missing-features

So, i created a website using dreamweaver and added a few images and videos. The images and videos are clearly visible in all other browsers except IE 11. Only a few images are visible in IE 11 (one of them is a .jpg and the other is a .png). the rest of the images are .jpg and are not visible. Also, the videos get aborted on IE 11. Any Solutions?
The website is basically an ebook and contains a lot of text. Here is a sample of the code that works for all other browser except IE11.
`

```
                <div id="sectionId1" class="pageContainer currentPage clearfix">
                    <h1 class="pageTitle">Introduction To the Ages</h1>
                    <div class="contentHolder" id="sectionId1">

                            <p class="text"> <img width="620" height="410" src="images/clip_image002.jpg" alt="">We humans have lived through numerous technological revolutions. This technological revolutions have always made many aspects of our life much easier and helped us to push towards a whole new era...humans gave life to the <strong>INFORMATION AGE</strong>.</p>
                        </div>                          
                    </div>`
....
</div></div></div>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="js/app.js"></script> -->
<script src="js/site.js"></script>
```

Note: I was able to fix the images by converting them to RGB. But the videos are still aborted.

Comment: Can we see the HTML code you are having problems with?

Comment: Does the browser's error console report any errors?

Comment: try running html validation on your code

Comment: @ShaunLoftin the website i created contains a lot of text, so it uploaded the following codes...
and the console does not show any errors...

Comment: @ScottSimpson, how can i do this? BTW i am a beginner...

Comment: Here is one validator: https://html5.validator.nu/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i found a weird solution. I opened a blank HTML and copied and pasted all the codes to the new html. After that the problem was fixed... I have no idea why... The old html still shows problem, but the new one has exactly same codes but works just fine...